# Python TypeError: integer argument expected, got float

Tags: opencv, draw, typeerror

Hello I am trying to run code that involves drawing a box but keeps returning the error

```
TypeError: integer argument expected, got float
```

The first issue in the code that appeared was

```
def draw_box(Image, x, y, w, h):
    cv2.line(Image, (x, y), (x + (w/5) ,y), WHITE, 2)
    cv2.line(Image, (x+((w/5)*4), y), (x+w, y), WHITE, 2)
    cv2.line(Image, (x, y), (x, y+(h/5)), WHITE, 2)
    cv2.line(Image, (x+w, y), (x+w, y+(h/5)), WHITE, 2)
    cv2.line(Image, (x, (y+(h/5*4))), (x, y+h), WHITE, 2)
    cv2.line(Image, (x, (y+h)), (x + (w/5) ,y+h), WHITE, 2)
    cv2.line(Image, (x+((w/5)*4), y+h), (x + w, y + h), WHITE, 2)
    cv2.line(Image, (x+w, (y+(h/5*4))), (x+w, y+h), WHITE, 2)
```

Which I fixed by replacing the division signs with python floor division, though then the next area of box drawing which returns the same Type Error

```
cv2.rectangle(Image, (Name_X_pos-10, Name_y_pos-25), (Name_X_pos +10 + (len(NAME) * 7), Name_y_pos-1), (0,0,0), -2)
```

I've tried putting cv2.rectangle(int(Image, (Name_..  only to receive back

```
TypeError: int() takes at most 2 arguments (5 given)
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: You don't want `int(Image, (Name)..)` -- you want to cast the individual numbers as integers, so for e.g. `(int(Name_X_pos+10+len(NAME)*7), ...)`

Comment: I did that and it now returned the error  
"ValueError: int() base must be >= 2 and <= 36"

Comment: You're including multiple arguments in `int()`. Just do one number at a time (look carefully at the code I just sent).

Comment: e.g. `cv2.rectangle(Image, (int(Name_X_pos-10), int(Name_y_pos-25)), (int(Name_X_pos +10 + (len(NAME) * 7)), int(Name_y_pos-1)), (0,0,0), -2)`

Comment: That fixed it. I appreciate the help

Comment: Great! I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

As with the original error, the problem in your `rectangle()` call is that the arguments which specify pixel coordinates are not integers. Even though there's no division, it's not clear whether some of your original variables are floats or if multiplying just converted some of them to floats and not integers...either way, if you just cast each coordinate as an integer, you should be good to go. For e.g.:

```
cv2.rectangle(Image,
              (int(Name_X_pos-10), int(Name_y_pos-25)),
              (int(Name_X_pos +10 + (len(NAME) * 7)), int(Name_y_pos-1)),
              (0,0,0), -2)
```